# In Monopoly, if your Community Chest card reads "Go back to ...." , do you move forward or backward?

Tags: monopoly

In Monopoly, if your Community Chest card reads "Go back to ...." , do you move forward or backward?

Comment: This page lists all the community chest cards, and none of them say "go back to." What edition do you have, and what is the complete text? https://monopoly.fandom.com/wiki/Community_Chest

Comment: I don't know what version that page is based on, but I certainly remember the monopoly set I played on as a kid having a "go back to old kent road" card.

Comment: @jejorda2 Chance has a Go Back Three {3} Spaces card.

Comment: @PeterGreen - Not just you. :-) And it's listed on [this page](https://enacademic.com/dic.nsf/enwiki/7021822) as *"Cards in the UK Standard Edition which are derived from the 1935 Darrow/Parker Brothers edition and are now omitted in the U.S. edition, or are entirely new"* along with "Go Back to Baltic Avenue" which was apparently in four U.S. editions prior to 1936.

Comment: @jejorda2 - See above. UK editions have "Go Back to Old Kent Road," and a long time ago there were four U.S. editions that had "Go Back to Baltic Avenue."

Comment: why do you even need to ask whether "go back"  means to go forwards or backwards?

Comment: What part of "back" do you not understand?

Comment: @user253751 Passing Go and collecting $200.

Answer (score 42):

It says 'Go *back* to', so that definitely means backwards. There are no tricks involved, it's just plain English.

There are other cards for moving forwards, e.g. a ([Chance](https://monopoly.fandom.com/wiki/Chance)) card which says 'Advance to Boardwalk'; they use a different phrase.

Comment: And the 'go  (directly) to jail' cards, which don't care about forwards or backwards but tell you to [go there right away](https://monopoly.fandom.com/wiki/Go_to_Jail_(card)). The 'do not pass GO' variety. Forward, backward, [right to jail](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eiyfwZVAzGw), those are the options.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for "go back to" is to prevent you from passing GO and collecting $200.

Comment: Unless the target tile is in front of you, in which case backwards actually puts you over GO, right? The cards that don't want you to pass go explicitly say so.

Comment: @mast Exactly. In fact it could be just as likely to make you pass GO, which makes the above answer incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

In the standard Monopoly game, there are no Community Chest cards that say "go back."

There IS one Chance card that says "Go back three spaces." That is basically the only time in the game when you would "go back."